# How to implement Kriging without x and y coordinates

Tags: geostatistics, kriging

I have some sample measurements taken from different locations. I want to predict the measurements in some surrounding locations that were not studies, for this I want to use Kriging. However, My measurements are taken from some depth, thus my only indicator of the location is the depth, there is no x-y coordinates. when I checked Kriging implementation I found that it requires x-y coordinates as indicators for the location. But I don't have these, is there a way to implement the algorithm using the depth only?

Thank You.

Comment: You want to estimate some property of the soil, say its humidity or temperature, based on samples at various depths? That's a straightforward regression problem. Obviously, the estimate will depend only on the depth, if that is your only input, rather than the location.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I have around 12 different measurements, I'm not sure if all of them depend on depth, can I still use Kriging? I want to use it because it may produces more accurate results. If regression is more suitable, which type of regression do you recommend? Thanks.

Comment: I do not quite follow; if you disregard the depth because it is irrelevant, what else could you base your predictions off? Your sample size is small too.

Comment: I think that the only relationship depends on depth, other relationships in this case may be inaccurate. I think predicting a some value related to its surroundings may be more accurate. My sample size is around 3000 records. I've seen this example http://www.google.com.sa/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.researchgate.net%2Fpublictopics.PublicPostFileLoader.html%3Fid%3D506efa19e39d5e7d3e000001%26key%3D79e41506efa19c9970&ei=n7CFVfPiOanRygO_3ojoAQ&usg=AFQjCNFQx5TplZqk1z9sQRznXTiNaKctqA&sig2=tUKJYx3aCV1oNEFWkgX0EQ  which uses x only, so is it possible?

Comment: Can we regard the depth as y only and do as in the example above?

Comment: I thought you had 12 measurements. What do you have 12 of?

Comment: Edit: the 12 things are the attributes, I have measures like depth, density, and the weights of some molecules found at different depths. All measurements are continuous, I have no discrete numeric value.

Comment: Sure, you can krige in one dimension (such as depth). It's likely to be fruitless in your application because spatial location will be important--but if you have enough data you could always try. That's not the first or even the second thing you should do, though, especially if you're unfamiliar with kriging. Focus first on adopting a suitable statistical model and using procedures that you understand and are appropriate for your analytical objectives.